# Directx9 C++ How to load texture from a part of a massive image

Tags: c++, image, directx, directx-9

What's a good way to load a part of a massive image into memory and convert it into a texture? Just trying to load the whole image to a texture and using StretchRect will not work, because if you try to load an image that is 17000 pixels in width for example, it will not work on most GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a texture with part of an image (I will assume you want a contiguous sub-rectangle) is essentially the same as doing so with the entire image. In D3D9, you `LockRect` on your target texture, and write the image contents. Instead of writing the entire contents of the image, just write the bytes, row by row, starting with the sub-rectangle's y-origin, and offsetting each row's source by the sub-rectangle's x-origin.

Of course, your target texture will still need to adhere to the texture size limitations.

Comment: But that is what I'm trying to get around. I want to be able to load things without adhering to texture size limitations.

Comment: You cannot create a texture larger than your driver will allow. Your question asks how to load part of an image - perhaps you should clarify.